# Git: alias not parsing string argument when using --author

Tags: git, alias

In my `~/.gitconfig`, I have something like

```
[alias]
    ac = !git add --all && git commit -m
    mileung = !git add --all && git commit --author="MyUserName <my@email.com>" -m
```

Running `git ac "message"` works, but running `git mileung "another message"` yields `git add --all && git commit --author=MyUserName <my@email.com> -m: my@email.com: No such file or directory`

Comment: Try to replace quotes (`"`) with apostrophes (`'`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Git reads configuration file lines, it uses double quotes to quote text, to avoid specially interpreting the characters.  The result is that *after* this parsing your alias reads:

```
!git add --all && git commit --author=MyUserName <my@email.com> -m
```

which is a slightly odd spacing and minor re-arrangement of:

```
!git add --all && git commit --author=MyUserName < my@email.com > -m
```

which tells the shell to direct the `git commit` command's input from the file `my@email.com` and write its output to the file `-m`.

You can either escape the quotes here, or use a different kind of quote as [bimlas suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50921065/git-alias-not-parsing-string-argument-when-using-author#comment88841811_50921065):

```
mileung = !git add --all && git commit --author=\"MyUserName <my@email.com>\" -m
```

(this version keeps Git from eating the double quotes, so that the shell sees them and the *shell* eats them instead while also protecting the angle brackets and spaces), or:

```
mileung = !git add --all && git commit --author='MyUserName <my@email.com>' -m
```

(here Git does not eat single quotes, so the shell sees the single quotes, uses them to quote the angle brackets and spaces, and then eats the single quotes).

(This problem is not at all unique to Git; see, e.g., [Trouble escaping quotes in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18535178/1256452).)